# How can I do pagination with Bluebird Promises?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I have something like

```
new Promise (resolve, reject) ->
  trader.getTrades limit, skip, (err, trades) ->
    return reject err if err

    resolve trades
.each (trade) ->
  doStuff trade
```

`limit` is set to some arbitrary number, say `10` and `skip` starts at `0`. I want to keep increasing `skip` until there are no more `trades`.

The `doStuff` is a function I'm using to process each trade.

This works the first time, but I want to get more trades in a paginated fashion. Specifically, I want to run `trader.getTrades` with a higher `skip` until `trades.length` is 0

Comment: Show us the docs of `trader.getTrades` and what values `limit` and `skip` have.

Comment: Are you actually using the promise somehow or is that `.each doStuff` sideeffect all of your code?

Comment: `trader.getTrades` isn't a real function. Think of it as a way to return trades from a data store.

Comment: Also, do you know from the 1st response what the total items are?  Or you want to call with higher `skip` value until `trades.length===0`??

Comment: OK. So what does "paginated fashion" mean for you exactly? If you tell us what you want, I can tell you how to do it, otherwise the answer to your question is "yes" :-)

Comment: I have to keep going until `trades.length === 0` with `skip`.

Comment: Edited question to answer comments

Comment: @Shamoon what version of node/io.js are you using?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to use [`promisify()`/`promisifyAll()`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisification) to convert `trader.getTrades()` to an async version that returns a promise.  Then, something like this should work well:

```
function getAllTrades(limit, offset, query) {

    var allTrades = [];

    function getTrades(limit, offset, query){
        return trader.getTradesAsync(limit, offset, query)
            .each(function(trade) {
                allTrades.push(trade)
                // or, doStuff(trade), etc.
            })
            .then(function(trades) {
                if (trades.length === limit) {
                    offset += limit;
                    return getTrades(limit, offset, query);
                } else {
                    return allTrades;
                }
            })
            .catch(function(e) {
                console.log(e.stack);
            })
    }

    return getTrades(limit, offset, query)
}
```

If you knew the total # of trades in advance you could use a different strategy with `.map` and `{concurrency: N}` to get N pages of trades at once.

Comment: I like the clever hack with allTrades and the closure but you can really solve this much more elegantly by concatenating the old result to the new one instead.

Comment: Well, true, however with the proliferation of HFT and everything I figure these will be huuge arrays, and better to play it safe ;)

Answer (score 8):

First, lets conceal that ugly callback api:

```
var getTrades = Promise.promisify(trader.getTrades, trader);
```

Now, to traverse that pagination api we'll use a simple recursive descent:

```
function getAllTrades(limit, arr) {
    if (!arr) arr=[];
    return getTrades(limit, arr.length).then(function(results) {
         if (!results.length)
             return arr;
         else
             return getAllTrades(limit, arr.concat(results));
    });
}
```

<sup>Admittedly, `concat` is not super-fast as it creates a new array after each request, but this is the most elegant.</sup>

This function will return a promise that resolves with a huge array of all results when all requests are made. This of course might not be what you want - maybe you want to show the first results immediately, and load more only lazily? Then a single promise is not the tool that you want, as this behaviour is more stream-like. It can however be written with promises nonetheless:

```
getTradeChunks = (limit, start = 0) ->
  getTrades limit, start
  .then (chunk) ->
    throw new Error("end of stream") if not chunk.length
    s = start+chunk.length
    [chunk, -> getTradeChunks limit, s]

rec = ([chunk, cont]) ->
  Promise.each chunk, doStuff
  .then -> waitForClick $ "#more"
  .then cont
  .then rec, err
end = (err) ->
  $ "#more"
  .text "no more trades"
getTradeChunks 15
.then rec, err
```

Comment: The cleanest? Now I wonder - if only there was a method for aggregation :) I think this could be a use case for supporting generic iterables there.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: Do you mean the [collection methods](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#collections)? I don't see how they could be used here.

Comment: Wow, cool, is that also in plain JS?  I now use [ps.map](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promise-streams#psmap) for doing simliar, but want option without stream conception.

Comment: @aarosil: No, it's coffeescript just as the OPs original code

Comment: Any way to avoid having a MASSIVE array? As I very well may end up with an array that will bust the limit of the machine

Comment: @Shamoon Of course you can omit the array and only pass its length through. But why would you want to traverse the whole thing at all if the results break your machine? That's why I asked for your use case in the original comments.

Comment: Why are you throwing an error if there is no `chunk`?

Comment: @Shamoon: To signal the end of the stream (I had hoped that would be clear from the message :-/). In the example it would then be used to remove the `#more`-button after all chunks are loaded and stuff was done to them. Of course, this is only one method to consume such a stream, and there are other ways of representing a data stream with promises.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my own solution to paging through promises: method [page](https://github.com/vitaly-t/spex/blob/master/docs/code/page.md), as part of the [spex](https://github.com/vitaly-t/spex) library.

It also lets you throttle the processing and provide load balancing as needed.

#### Example

```
var promise = require('bluebird');
var spex = require('spex')(promise);

function source(index, data, delay) {
    // create and return an array/page of mixed values
    // dynamically, based on the index of the sequence;
    switch (index) {
        case 0:
            return [0, 1, promise.resolve(2)];
        case 1:
            return [3, 4, promise.resolve(5)];
        case 2:
            return [6, 7, promise.resolve(8)];
    }
    // returning nothing/undefined indicates the end of the sequence;
    // throwing an error will result in a reject;
}

function dest(idx, data, delay) {
    // data - resolved array data;
    console.log("LOG:", idx, data, delay);
}

spex.page(source, dest)
    .then(function (data) {
        console.log("DATA:", data); // print result;
    });
```

#### Output

```
LOG: 0 [ 0, 1, 2 ] undefined
LOG: 1 [ 3, 4, 5 ] 3
LOG: 2 [ 6, 7, 8 ] 0
DATA: { pages: 3, total: 9, duration: 7 }
```