# Javascript - Google Drive v3 API and functions

Tags: javascript, promise, google-drive-api, refactoring, google-api-js-client

Trying to create a connection to the google drive v3 api using the JavaScript SDK.

Basically the end goal I want to achieve is to access various files from google drive and add in metadata (but not got quite that far yet).

Ran through the tutorial on the google drive api guides (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/js) that works fine and i'm able to authorise myself to access files etc

What i'm struggling with is trying to clean up the code so I don't end up repeating myself over and over.

I've used the GDrive Python SDK and i can use that fine but i'm really struggling with the JavaScript SDK, it might just be I need a reality check as i'm trying to bring python aspects into JavaScript?

So the code below loops through each search results page and find all the files in my gDrive with the extension ZIP, RAR or TAR and then inserts the results into a HTML (building upon the google drive example):

```
function listFiles() {
    gapi.client.load('drive', 'v3', function () {
        gapi.client.init({}
        ).then(function () {
            gapi.client.drive.files.list({
                'q': "fileExtension = 'zip' or fileExtension = 'rar' or fileExtension = 'tar'",
                'pageSize': 10,
                'fields': "nextPageToken, files(id, name)",
            }).then(function (respo) {
                var token = respo.result.nextPageToken;
                gapi.client.drive.files.list({
                    'q': "fileExtension = 'zip' or fileExtension = 'rar' or fileExtension = 'tar'",
                    'fields': "nextPageToken, files(id, name)",
                    'pageToken': token
                }).then(function (result) {
                    appendPre('Files:');
                    console.log(result);
                    var files = result.result.files;
                    if (files && files.length > 0) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                            var file = files[i];
                            console.log(files[i]);
                            arr.push(files[i]);
                            appendPre(file.name + ' (' + file.id + ')');
                        }
                    } else {
                        appendPre('No files found.');
                    }
                })
            });
        });
    });
}
```

This works, but how do I go about cleaning it up? Creating functions for example? I'll probably need to request this file list regularly so I tried creating a function:

```
function getFiles() {gapi.client.load('drive', 'v3', function () {
    gapi.client.init({}
        ).then(function () {
            gapi.client.drive.files.list({
                'q': "fileExtension = 'zip' or fileExtension = 'rar' or fileExtension = 'tar'",
                'pageSize': 10,
                'fields': "nextPageToken, files(id, name)",
            }).then(function (respo) {
                var token = respo.result.nextPageToken;
                gapi.client.drive.files.list({
                    'q': "fileExtension = 'zip' or fileExtension = 'rar' or fileExtension = 'tar'",
                    'fields': "nextPageToken, files(id, name)",
                    'pageToken': token
                })
            })
        })
    });
}
```

but when I call it I just get 'undefined'

I then read somewhere that I could create it as a variable and call it with a '.then' like I had done in the complete example.

But this give 'undefined' when calling the variable and when doing a '.then':

> getFiles.then(function (respo){console.log(respo)})
>
> Unable to get property 'then' of undefined or null reference

What am I doing wrong? Clearly something, probably something really stupid =[

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated =]

Comment: If this information was not useful for your situation, I'm sorry. In your script, you use ``pageSize: 10``. If the number of files you want to search is less than 1000, you can retrieve them by one API call by using ``pageSize: 1000``.

Comment: Create a thenable function that gets the authorized client, and then pass that client object to a function that also takes your needed parameters (search query, etc) and returns the promise.

Comment: This question may be useful - it uses bluebird promises but details how you can exhaust a paginated resource: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28549164/9337071

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code, it is working on my side. After authentication, you don't need to call `gapi.client.init({}).then()` again.

Here is working code:

```
function initClient() {
        gapi.client.init({
          discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
          clientId: CLIENT_ID,
          scope: SCOPES
        }).then(function () {
          // Listen for sign-in state changes.
          gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);

          // Handle the initial sign-in state.
          updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
          authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
          //signoutButton.onclick = handleSignoutClick;

          gapi.client.drive.files.list({
                'q': "fileExtension = 'zip' or fileExtension = 'rar' or fileExtension = 'tar'",
                'pageSize': 10,
                'fields': "nextPageToken, files(id, name)",
            }).then(function (respo) {
                appendPre('Files:');
          var files = respo.result.files;
          if (files && files.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
              var file = files[i];
              appendPre(file.name + ' (' + file.id + ')');
            }
          } else {
            appendPre('No files found.');
          }
            })
        });
      }
```

I've added your code to the initial `initClient()` and it works as intended.

@Tanaike is correct, you can adjust your `pageSize` to 1000 to get all files in one page. But try reading this [tutorial](http://www.codingsection.com/getting-list-of-files-and-folders-using-google-drive-api.html) to implement `nextpageToken`

---

**UPDATE**

If you are referring to functions being called inside a function for java script then it is possible and it is also present in the Javascript quickstart.

```
/**
       *  Initializes the API client library and sets up sign-in state
       *  listeners.
       */
      function initClient() {
        gapi.client.init({
          discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
          clientId: CLIENT_ID,
          scope: SCOPES
        }).then(function () {
          // Listen for sign-in state changes.
          gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);

          // Handle the initial sign-in state.
          updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
          authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
          signoutButton.onclick = handleSignoutClick;
        });
      }

      /**
       *  Called when the signed in status changes, to update the UI
       *  appropriately. After a sign-in, the API is called.
       */
      function updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
        if (isSignedIn) {
          authorizeButton.style.display = 'none';
          signoutButton.style.display = 'block';
          listFiles();
        } else {
          authorizeButton.style.display = 'block';
          signoutButton.style.display = 'none';
        }
      }
 /**
       * Print files.
       */
      function listFiles() {
        gapi.client.drive.files.list({
          'pageSize': 10,
          'fields': "nextPageToken, files(id, name)"
        }).then(function(response) {
          appendPre('Files:');
          var files = response.result.files;
          if (files && files.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
              var file = files[i];
              appendPre(file.name + ' (' + file.id + ')');
            }
          } else {
            appendPre('No files found.');
          }
        });
      }
```

If you'll check the code, `initClient()` calls a function `updateSigninStatus` which also call `listFiles()` that prints available files in your Drive.

Comment: Thanks both for coming back but I think I might have confused the question. I'm aware this code works. The question is how do separate it and call it as a function to call later on? Is it even possible? For example in my python code I've have a function for getting the file data then another for collecting meta and another for tagging the files with new meta, I can then use that again and again... but with JavaScript I only seem to be able to do it in blocks of long code repeating myself instead of just calling functions. Sorry if i'm not making sense.